# Eclipse Scout Neon unit test of execChangedMasterValue

Tags: eclipse-scout

I have two fields that are connected with master-slave relationship :

```
public class Slave extends AbstractListBox<String> {

  @Override
  protected Class<? extends IValueField> getConfiguredMasterField() {

    return Master.class;
  }

  @Override
  protected void execChangedMasterValue(final Object newMasterValue) {
    this.function() // -> here I put debugging break point
  }
}

public class Master extends AbstractBooleanField {

  @Override
  protected void execChangedValue() {

    super.execChangedValue(); // -> Break point 2 
  }
}
```

I write unit test for this relationship, but inside unit test `execChangedMasterValue` is never called.

My unit test looks like :

```
@Test
public void test() {

    this.box.getMaster.setValue(true)
    Assert.assertFalse(... something from function Slave ...)
}
```

Unit tests always failed, and if I put breakpoints as described above, debugger stops only on second break point but never on first one.

In "real" world, function is called and everything works as it should.

Is there a reason that `execChangedMasterValue` is not called? Is behaviour of `execChangedMasterValue` different from `changedValue()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce what you are describing. I took the Scout HelloWorld Project (the one that is generated when you create a new project).

In the `HelloWorldForm` I have added this "slave" field in the `MainBox`:

```
@Order(2000)
public class LengthField extends AbstractIntegerField {
    @Override
    protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
        return TEXTS.get("Length");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends IValueField<?>> getConfiguredMasterField() {
        return MessageField.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void execChangedMasterValue(Object newMasterValue) {
        if(newMasterValue instanceof String) {
            String s = (String) newMasterValue;
            setValue(s.length());
        } else {
            setValue(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the example Unit Test `HelloWorldFormTest`, I have added an additional check to `testMessageCorrectlyImported()`:

```
/**
 * Tests that the {@link MessageField} is correctly filled after start.
 */
@Test
public void testMessageCorrectlyImported() {
    HelloWorldForm frm = new HelloWorldForm();
    frm.start();

    Assert.assertEquals("Message field", MESSAGE_VALUE, frm.getMessageField().getValue());
    Assert.assertEquals("Length field", Integer.valueOf(MESSAGE_VALUE.length()) , frm.getLengthField().getValue());

    frm.getMessageField().setValue("abcdef");
    Assert.assertEquals("Length field (after update)", Integer.valueOf("abcdef".length()), frm.getLengthField().getValue());
}
```

Everything works as expected…

Comment: Yes, the example above works, but what if you setValue() on MassageField inside unit test? So for example HelloWorldForm frm = new HelloWorldForm(); frm.getMessageField.setValue("My message")...

Comment: I have updated the test and it is always green in my workspace. Maybe you did not start the form in your test case?